# GWT session management

Tags: java, session, gwt, servlets, session-management

I don't too much about gwt session on java. I've some doubts about it. Anyone can check if the implementation below is the way it needs to be done.

```
public class ServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements Service  
{
   void CreateSession(String Username)
   {
      HttpServletRequest request = this.getThreadLocalRequest();
      HttpSession session = request.getSession();
      session.setAttribute("Username", Username);
   }

   boolean ValidateSession(String Username)
   {
       HttpServletRequest request = this.getThreadLocalRequest();
       HttpSession session = request.getSession();
       if (session.getAttribute("Username"))
       {
          return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
}
```

Is this the correct way to implement these two function???

Comment: ` if (session.getAttribute("Username"))` will this compile ?

Comment: [Here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/cprs_best_practice.html) are some best practices on session management hope this will help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a few correction

```
    void createSession(String Username) {
        getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().setAttribute("Username", Username);
    }

    boolean validateSession(String Username) {
        if (getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getAttribute("Username") != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there anyway, I can identify a valid session with the use of any username and only the thread??

Comment: traditional java/jsp/servlet programming. write any servlet or jsp and take the session from the request

Comment: I'm new to java, Can u show me a simple example to perform this

Comment: @Noor here is the simple java session tutorial. http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Session-Tracking.html

Comment: Can I annotate this as @Stateless, so I can scale horizontally?

Answer (score 5):

This [LoginSecurityFAQ](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/LoginSecurityFAQ) is a good place to start.